# How to get Header Authorization on code igniter 4?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I create restful api using code igniter 4 and JWT. Login API worked fine and generated auth token. But I cant get login detail using token, it shows an error (null value) while trying to get authorization token.

```
public function details(){
        $key        = $this->getKey();
        $authHeader = $this->request->getHeader("Authorization"); //return null
        $authHeader = $authHeader->getValue(); //line 149 error, caused $authHeader is null
        $token      = $authHeader;
        // $token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJUaGVfY2xhaW0iLCJhdWQiOiJUaGVfQXVkIiwiaWF0IjoxNjQxNTQ0MTQzLCJuYmYiOjE2NDE1NDQxNTMsImV4cCI6MTY0MTU0Nzc0MywiZGF0YSI6eyJpZCI6IjkiLCJhY2NvdW50X2lkIjoiY2ljY2NjIiwibmFtZSI6ImNvZGUgaWduaXRlciJ9fQ.TI3zztWxIYZxoa_vhTB04YoGMaq4GdD4bxzmrt8QAH0";

        try{
            $decoded = JWT::decode($token,$key,array("HS256"));

            if($decoded){
                $response = [
                    'status'    => 200,
                    'error'     => false,
                    'message'   => 'Account details',
                    'data'      => [
                        'account'   => $decoded
                    ]
                ];
                return $this->respondCreated($response);
            }
        }catch(Exception $ex){
            $response = [
                'status'    => 401,
                'error'     => true,
                'message'   =>'Access denied',
                'data'      => []
            ];
            return $this->respondCreated($response);
        }
    }
```

result on postman

```
{
    "title": "Error",
    "type": "Error",
    "code": 500,
    "message": "Call to a member function getValue() on null",
    "file": "/var/www/html/project-root/app/Controllers/Account.php",
    "line": 149,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/project-root/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php",
            "line": 825,
            "function": "details",
            "class": "App\\Controllers\\Account",
            "type": "->",
            "args": []
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/project-root/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php",
            "line": 412,
            "function": "runController",
            "class": "CodeIgniter\\CodeIgniter",
            "type": "->",
            "args": [
                {}
            ]
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/project-root/vendor/codeigniter4/framework/system/CodeIgniter.php",
            "line": 320,
            "function": "handleRequest",
            "class": "CodeIgniter\\CodeIgniter",
            "type": "->",
            "args": [
                null,
                {
                    "handler": "file",
                    "backupHandler": "dummy",
                    "storePath": "/var/www/html/project-root/writable/cache/",
                    "cacheQueryString": false,
                    "prefix": "",
                    "ttl": 60,
                    "reservedCharacters": "{}()/\\@:",
                    "file": {
                        "storePath": "/var/www/html/project-root/writable/cache/",
                        "mode": 416
                    },
                    "memcached": {
                        "host": "127.0.0.1",
                        "port": 11211,
                        "weight": 1,
                        "raw": false
                    },
                    "redis": {
                        "host": "127.0.0.1",
                        "password": null,
                        "port": 6379,
                        "timeout": 0,
                        "database": 0
                    },
                    "validHandlers": {
                        "dummy": "CodeIgniter\\Cache\\Handlers\\DummyHandler",
                        "file": "CodeIgniter\\Cache\\Handlers\\FileHandler",
                        "memcached": "CodeIgniter\\Cache\\Handlers\\MemcachedHandler",
                        "predis": "CodeIgniter\\Cache\\Handlers\\PredisHandler",
                        "redis": "CodeIgniter\\Cache\\Handlers\\RedisHandler",
                        "wincache": "CodeIgniter\\Cache\\Handlers\\WincacheHandler"
                    }
                },
                false
            ]
        },
        {
            "file": "/var/www/html/project-root/public/index.php",
            "line": 35,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "CodeIgniter\\CodeIgniter",
            "type": "->",
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

postman screenshot
[image]

and if I hardcode token, I can get login detail. Why this line `$authHeader = $this->request->getHeader("Authorization");` return null?

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
SetEnvIf Authorization "(.*)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Comment: check my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is the way I use to fetch Authorization token for the header.

In public/.htaccess file I have configuration as following:

```
# Disable directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# Rewrite engine
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------

# Turning on the rewrite engine is necessary for the following rules and features.
# FollowSymLinks must be enabled for this to work.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # If you installed CodeIgniter in a subfolder, you will need to
    # change the following line to match the subfolder you need.
    # http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritebase
    # RewriteBase /

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
        RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Rewrite "www.example.com -> example.com"
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

    # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    # such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    # request to the front controller, index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]

    # Ensure Authorization header is passed along
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
    ErrorDocument 404 index.php
</IfModule>

# Disable server signature start
    ServerSignature Off
# Disable server signature end
```

And in the controller apache_request_headers() wrapper is used to get the header.

```
$authorization = apache_request_headers()["Authorization"];
```

This will only work with Apache server though.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On    
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule .* - [e=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

Then get header like this

```
$this->request->getServer('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')
```

**update**

I noticed you are not using `Authorization` tab but setting header manually. If you set Authorization header manually make sure value field starts with `Bearer`  like

```
Bearer eyJ....
```

or simply use Authorization tab and select `Bearer Token`

Comment: Sorry, I got same error. `$this->request->getServer('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')` returns null

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak check my updated answer

Comment: thanks for the answer. I tried to use Authorization tab and add `Bearer`, both were not working. `$this->request->getServer('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION')` still returns null

Comment: Then I suggest you to `var_dump($this->request);` to see what headers you receive.

Comment: `var_dump` result is here https://pastebin.com/0mvwARCy

Comment: You sure that `.htaccess` configuration is working right? Also make sure no other filters like CSRF or other custom filters intercepts and redirects or clears the headers. Besides that I've no other suggestions for now.

Comment: I've updated the question and added my `.htaccess`, I put it on root project folder