# How do I add basic authentication to a Codeigniter 4 REST API?

Tags: php, api, rest, authentication, codeigniter

I have a very basic Codeigniter 4 REST API with only one user and one function (POST). I need to add basic authentication where the username and password are in the HTTP authentication header. How do I add that to the code below? i don't need anything very sophisticated, just enough to authenticate the one user.

```
namespace App\Controllers;
use CodeIgniter\RESTful\ResourceController;
use CodeIgniter\API\ResponseTrait;
use App\Models\ApiModel;
use Config\Services;

class Api extends ResourceController {

    use ResponseTrait;
    protected $request;

    public function create() {
        $model = new ApiModel();
            
        $data = [
            'uid' => $this->request->getPost('uid'),
            'request' => $this->request->getPost('request'),
            'data' => $this->request->getPost('data')
        ];
             
        $model->insert($data);

        $response = [
            'status'   => 201,
            'error'    => null,
            'messages' => [
                'success' => 'Data Saved'
            ]
        ];
             
        return $this->respondCreated($data, 201);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use `$this->request->getHeader("Authorization");` (change the header name if neccesary) to get that information, then proceed to validate the credentials.

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the fast response. When I run it through Postman and var_dump the result of that header, it's NULL... any reason why? I have basic authentication set in PM with the username and password entered.

Comment: If I var_dump $this->request->headers() I get the error "Call to undefined method CodeIgniter\\HTTP\\IncomingRequest::headers()" - am I missing an include somewhere?

Comment: Hi @Ping could you solve it? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Authorization header is disabled by default in the server, you can modify your server configuration so that header is active. This may help you [How to get Header Authorization on code igniter 4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70649316/how-to-get-header-authorization-on-code-igniter-4)

If that doesn't work you can also use another header name like "Authorization2".